# Input::old in edit page

Tags: php, orm, laravel, eloquent

How I can use **Input::old()** in edit page, when value is

```
{{ $user->name }}
```

But, if **name** is invalid¹, or something, how I can get the Input::old() and **override** {{ $user->name }} ?

For example:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Nome" class='span12' value="{{ $user->name }}" />
```

¹ *fail in validation test*

Comment: What does `invalid` mean?

Comment: @JosephSilber if isn't validate, understand? If name min:4 or required, or unique.. whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{{ Form::text(
     'name', 
      Input::old('name', $user->name), 
      array('class' => 'span12','placeholder' => 'Name')
)}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I'm correctly, but in **Developer Api**, have this:

```
 public static function old($key = null, $default = null)
 {
     return array_get(Session::get(Input::old_input, array()), $key, $default);
 }
```

So, I can use:

```
{{ Input::old('name', $user->name) }}
```

Right?

So, I think is that. If I not correctly, please tell me.

Anyway, Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 1):

My first/quick guess is that you've not called flash() ahead of time, which is needed to place the input values into the session in the first place...

```
Input::flash();
```

http://laravel.com/docs/input#old-input

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Nome" class='span12' value="{{old('name', $user->name) }}" />
```

and for checkbox

```
 <input id="main" class="form-check-inline"
 type="checkbox" name="position" {{old('position',$user->position)?'checked':''}}>
```